# Missing variable in the external validation cohort

Tags: predictive-models, validation

I have developed a model on my training cohort and I intent to use an external dataset to validate the model. However, one of the predictors used in the model was not captured in the external validation cohort. It is not possible to retrospectively capture the data.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there possibility for mass-imputation? Perhaps you could predict values of the missing variable? Is it interval/ratio variable or ordinal/nominal?